# Concatenate strings with += operator

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am really new to ASP.NET, C#.

Now I am trying to write a little method, what is build me an sql query.

(Later I will use prepared statements, now I am just try to get acquainted with the environment, with the language, etc...)

Here is my method:

```
    public void insert( string table, Dictionary<string, string> dataToInsert ) {
        string sql = "INSERT INTO " + table;

        if (dataToInsert.Count< 1) {
            throw new Exception("No data to insert to table: " + table);
        }

        List<string> fieldNames = getFieldNames(dataToInsert);
        List<string> aposthrofedFieldNames = getApostrophedValues(fieldNames);

        List<string> values = getValues(dataToInsert);
        List<string> aposthrofedValues = getApostrophedValues(values);

        string fieldNamesString = string.Join(", ", aposthrofedFieldNames);
        string valuesString = string.Join(", ", aposthrofedValues);

        sql += " (" + fieldNamesString + ") VALUES (" + valuesString + ")";
    }
```

The `fieldNamesString` and `valuesString` are just concatenated strings like `'userId', 'loginDate', ... so nothing special, just strings.

At this line:

```
sql += " (" + fieldNamesString + ") VALUES (" + valuesString + ")";
```

the `sql` variable has gone. Can not be watchable, no more datatip.

What do I do wrong?

**EDIT**

Screenshot:

[image]

**UPDATE**

If I am using this, `sql` will be ok:

```
sql = string.Concat(sql, " (", fieldNamesString, ") VALUES (", valuesString, ")");
```

Comment: When you say it's no longer watchable and no longer has a datatip, have you stepped outside the method at that point when debugging?

Comment: Why teach yourself to do things the wrong way first? The right approach to constructing SQL in code is to use parameters. Learn that way first and then you don't have more to learn.

Comment: Ensure you are building the project in debug mode instead of release mode.

Comment: since your issue relates to string concatenation which you state you're going to remove later anyway, why not save yourself the hassle and just do it properly to start with. It won't take any longer, and it'll save time overall.

Comment: sidepoint - It's `apostrophed`

Comment: Instead of string you should use StringBuilder to gain performance

Comment: please Add watch for sql, fieldNamesString & valuesString variables & let me know the values. -  @vaso123

Comment: @Rajan I've added the picture

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You are right, now I am writing the prepared statement version.  Anyway, the question was not that. Forget the sql part, lets focus on concatenate.